# home, end, delete, pageup, pagedown with ksh

Tags: shell, openbsd, ksh

I want to use home, end, delete, pageup, pagedown with ksh. My TERM is 
xterm-color. These keys works fine with tcsh and zsh, but not with ksh 
(print a tilda ~)

I found this:

```
bind '^[[3'=prefix-2
bind '^[[3~'=delete-char-forward
bind '^[[1'=prefix-2
bind '^[[1~'=beginning-of-line
bind '^[[4'=prefix-2
bind '^[[4~'=end-of-line
```

But when I set one bindkey, the last does not work anymore.

How can I use these keys in ksh with a .kshrc ?

Thanks.

Comment: Cross posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557112/home-end-delete-pageup-pagedown-with-ksh

Answer (score 2):

set -o emacs

should work.

Answer (score 2):

I made a file with this and others resources(like keys, functions, colors and a .bash_logout similar in ksh named .ksh_logout.

Check my dotfiles repository in github: https://bitbucket.org/afsec/dotfiles
The content of file `.ksh_keys`.

```
# Activate Delete
bind '^[[3~'=delete-char-forward

# Activate Home
bind '^[[1~'=beginning-of-line

# Activate End
bind '^[[4~'=end-of-line
```